# Read source address for UDP broadcast

Tags: c++, sockets, broadcast

My goal is to listen on broadcast address range `ff05:e671:2015::1` for udp datagrams. When such is received, the concrete server ip shall be recovered.

Currently, I am receiving valid packets. However, when I check the source address, here are a couple of outputs:

```
fd01:e671:2015:5c01::
fd01:e671:2015:d101::
```

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
std::array<char, 1024> _buff;
sockaddr a {};
socklen_t s = sizeof( a );
auto bytes = recvfrom( _fd, _buff.data(), _buff.size(), MSG_DONTWAIT | MSG_TRUNC, &a, &s );
...
// reuse the buffer
sockaddr_in6 *sin = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in6*>( &a );
inet_ntop( AF_INET6, &sin->sin6_addr, _buff.data(), INET6_ADDRSTRLEN );
```

Finally, here is some of the output of `tcpdump | grep fd01:e671:2015:5c01`:

```
10:07:31.452905 IP6 fd01:e671:2015:5c01:203:2dff:fe34:d598.20001 > ff05:e671:2015:5c01:203:2dff:fe34:d598.20001: UDP, length 120
10:07:31.453122 IP6 fd01:e671:2015:5c01:203:2dff:fe34:d598.20001 > ff05:e671:2015:5c01:203:2dff:fe34:d598.20001: UDP, length 161
10:07:31.453128 IP6 fd01:e671:2015:5c01:203:2dff:fe34:d598.20001 > ff05:e671:2015:5c01:203:2dff:fe34:d598.20001: UDP, length 202
10:07:31.453130 IP6 fd01:e671:2015:5c01:203:2dff:fe34:d598.20001 > ff05:e671:2015:5c01:203:2dff:fe34:d598.20001: UDP, length 80
10:07:31.453131 IP6 fd01:e671:2015:5c01:203:2dff:fe34:d598.20001 > ff05:e671:2015:5c01:203:2dff:fe34:d598.20001: UDP, length 121
10:07:31.453133 IP6 fd01:e671:2015:5c01:203:2dff:fe34:d598.20001 > ff05:e671:2015:5c01:203:2dff:fe34:d598.20001: UDP, length 162
```

How do I get the full and concrete datagram source ip?

Comment: What output did you expect? And what is `_buff`? What does `_buff.size()` return? What happens between the `recvfrom` call and the `inet_ntop` call (especially with `a`)? And have you checked that the address *is* an IPv6 address? Lastly, how do you *print* the output? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I expect something like `fd01:e671:2015:5c01:203:2dff:fe34:d598`. Also, as is evident, I expect boh C functions, writing in _buff, to place a delimiting `\0`.

Comment: What if `sizeof (sockaddr)` is 16 and `sizeof(sockaddr_in6)` is 28, which it is on my platform. How will the full address fit in `a`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz this seems to solve the problem! And I was wondering for hours! The documentation explicitly requests a sockaddr param:            `ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
                        struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);`. Could you post a short answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sockaddr` is too small to hold an IPv6 address. You should allocate the type you intend to hold and cast in the call to `recvfrom`. You can't do it the other way around because you don't actually have a `sockaddr_in6` that way.